# Change the color of a single itemize item — command to do that?

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

My question concerns `itemize item`s in `Beamer` slides. I want to obtain the following slide:
[image]

This has been produced by the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=red}
\item \textcolor{red}{Red}, other text
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=green}
\item \textcolor{green}{Green}, other text
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=blue} 
\item \textcolor{blue}{Blue}, other text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Question.** Is there a way to define a command `\coloreditem{<color>}` so that the above slide can be defined by the simplified code that follows?

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\coloreditem{red} \textcolor{red}{Red}, other text
\coloreditem{green} \textcolor{green}{Green}, other text
\item \textcolor{blue}{Blue}, other text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

My first guess was to define

```
\newcommand\coloreditem[1]{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=#1}\item}
```

but of course the local structure get changed for too long. And adding a new pair of `{}` does not work.

Comment: I didn't understand what is wrong. What do you mean by *changed for too long*? Both frames has the same format here.

Comment: I changed my second frame: The goal is that is does not change the following `\item`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\coloreditem[1]{\item[\textcolor{#1}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}]}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\coloreditem{red} blabl \textcolor{red}{Red}, other text
\coloreditem{green} blalba \textcolor{green}{Green}, other text
\item bnlabla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice, thanks! I didn't know the command `\beameritemnestingprefix` which is very useful here.

Answer (score 4):

If it is okay to define a command with two arguments you could use

```
\newcommand\coloreditem[2]{{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=#1}\item #2}}
```

Then the changed color is restricted to the single item.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\coloreditem[2]{{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=#1}\item #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Normal color, other text
\coloreditem{green}{\textcolor{green}{Green}, other text}
\item Normal color, other text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right, that is a solution. Though I would prefer a command that works the same as `\item`. I could then have commands like `\alertitem`, `\exampleitem` and so on. Also (or otherwise) I could have a supplementary argument to `\item` (maybe hard since there is already an optional argument) to make it `alerted` or `exampled`.

Comment: What about restore the default color after `\item` in the command definition?